# Statistics,standard deviation,spread,gemoetric meaning

Tags: geometry, statistics, standard-deviation

What are the *geometrical* interpretations/meanings of these statistical quantities:
**mean**, **standard deviation** and **spread**?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Geometric_interpretation

Comment: Ok. Now **mean** is the center of gravity,and what about **spread**?

Comment: In English 'spread' and 'variability' are usually generic terms for discussing how near to or far from the center elements of a population or sample are likely to fall. In other languages words that can be translated as 'spread' or 'variability' might more properly be translated (for use in statistics and probability) as 'range' and 'variance', respectively. Please give the formal definition of 'spread' as you are using it here.

Answer (score 1):

Spread is the measure of the dispersion of a choice or on a set of choices. The mean is the measure (average) of weighting of the values of the sample. The standard deviation is how much the dispersion differs from the mean reference.